How can I secure my Android app from CVE-2024 vulnerabilities and detect which CVEs affect my app?
I'm developing an Android app and I'm concerned about potential vulnerabilities related to CVE-2024. I would like to better understand how I can secure my app from these vulnerabilities and how to identify which CVEs might be affecting my app.
My specific questions are:

How can I determine which CVEs (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures) are relevant to my Android app?
Is there a process or tool available that can scan my app and detect whether it's affected by specific CVEs, particularly ones from 2024?
How do I secure my app from CVE-2024 vulnerabilities?
Are there best practices, patches, or specific updates I should be looking into to mitigate these security risks? If so, how do I implement these solutions in my app?
What are the general steps for resolving CVEs once they are identified?
Once I’ve detected that a specific CVE is affecting my app, what is the typical approach for addressing it? Should I update dependencies, apply patches, or take other actions?


Synk
https://snyk.io/learn/application-security/mobile-application-security/android-application-security/#android
dependency check
https://sonique6784.medium.com/keep-your-app-secure-with-dependencycheck-585d61aff3c
security config
https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config
these are some links which can help you to implement security features

Why only CVE-2024? In 2023 and before there wer also CVEs published.

To secure your Android App, you need to first find potential or actual problems like potential exposure or bugs to CVEs then figure out how to secure them.
It could be divide into two steps:
1- Investigate and check problems, bugs and potential threats in your app.
A. Check the Code (Static Analysis):

Decompile the APK: Use tools like APKTool or JD-GUI to break down your APK and peek at the source code. You’re looking for things like hardcoded sensitive info, API keys, or anything that shouldn’t be exposed.

Review the Manifest File: Open the AndroidManifest.xml and make sure you’re not using permissions or components (like Activities or Services) that are set to exported=true unless they really need to be.

Look for Vulnerable Code: Check your code for weak spots like insecure storage, careless use of WebView, or bad encryption practices.
Use ProGuard or R8:

Make sure your code is obfuscated. It won’t make your app bulletproof, but it’ll at least slow down someone trying to reverse-engineer it.


B. Run the App and Watch It (Dynamic Analysis):

Use a Debugger: Tools like Frida, JEB Decompiler, or Xposed Framework can help you inject code or debug your app as it runs. This is where you can see what’s really going on under the hood.

Check the Network Traffic: Tools like Burp Suite or Charles Proxy let you see what data your app is sending over the network. Make sure nothing sensitive is being sent as plain text.


Test on a Rooted Device:

Run your app on a rooted device to see if any security measures break down. If your app behaves differently, that’s a red flag.
Look for Injection Vulnerabilities:

Try different inputs to see if you can trick your app into doing something it shouldn’t, like SQL Injection or Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).

Check File and Data Security: Make sure any sensitive data stored locally is encrypted and not accessible to other apps.


C. Use Automated Tools:

Run Automated Scans : Tools like MobSF (Mobile Security Framework) can do some of the heavy lifting by automating both static and dynamic analysis. It’s a great way to catch common vulnerabilities.

How to Secure Your Android App:
A. Secure Your Code:

Never hardcode sensitive information: Never hardcode API keys, passwords, or any sensitive info in your source code. Use secure storage instead.

Write Secure Code: Always validate user input and sanitize data before using it. Stick to tried-and-true encryption methods instead of trying to invent your own.
Obfuscate Your Code:

Use tools like ProGuard or R8 to make your code harder to read and reverse-engineer.


B. Secure Network Communications:

Use HTTPS: Make sure all network traffic goes over HTTPS to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks. Consider using certificate pinning to ensure your app only talks to trusted servers.
Secure Your API Endpoints:

Ensure that your APIs have proper authentication and authorization checks. Use tokens like JWTs and rotate them regularly to keep things secure.


C. Protect Data on the Device:

Don’t Store Sensitive Data Unencrypted: Avoid storing sensitive info in plain text files or databases that other apps can access. Use the Android Keystore for storing sensitive data.
Detect Rooted Devices:

If you detect the app is running on a rooted device, consider disabling features that might be at risk.


D. Keep Your Users Safe:
Secure Login and Sessions:

Implement strong password rules: if possible, use multi-factor authentication. Manage sessions securely and make sure they expire properly on logout or timeout.

Handle Sessions Properly: Always secure session management and make sure sessions are invalidated when a user logs out or after a period of inactivity.


